# AFIncrementalStore - best design to prevent some records from being updated

Tags: rest, core-data, synchronization, afincrementalstore

Here is the use case:

- I am using AFIncrementalStore, in a fairly standard way
- When offline, user is still able to update some records
- I set up my own queue to upload edited records and process the queue when back online
- When back Online I also refetch data
- I want to make sure that my updated records don't get re-updated with the old data from the server when back online
- Whenever I edit a record, I flag it in core data as 'edited', and clear the flag only when it is successfully sent to server

The goal is:

- when I get results from server, if the results already exist in core
  data, but are flagged as 'updated' or 'deleted', I don't want them to
  be refreshed with values from the server

I am looking for the best design to achieve that, out of the box if possible. I would like to avoid subclassing.